# if/else with select value in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have got a "kategorie" select, and I try to get te value of selected answers.
Then by this value my website need to change the css atribute.

I don't know what is wrong, but this isnt working.
Please,help me.
Ps. Sorry for my english.

```
    $('select#kategorie').change(function() {
    var value = $('select#kategorie:selected').val();
    if (value=="1" || value=="10")
    {
    $("#liczba-pokoi").css("display","block");
    }
    if else (value=="2" || value=="11")
    {
    $("#liczba-pokoi").css("display","none");
    }
    if else ((value=="3" || value=="12")
    {
    $("#liczba-pokoi").css("display","none");
    }
    if else (value=="4" || value=="13")
    {
    $("#liczba-pokoi").css("display","block");
    }
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't working?"  Do you get an error?  Does it change the CSS class but not display as you expect?  Is it displaying the wrong class?  What happens and what do you expect?

Comment: Think about it logically. You have to declare `else` before you can make another `if` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tidier solution:

```
var val, liczba_pokoi = $("#liczba-pokoi");

$('#kategorie').change(function() {

  val = $(this).val();

  if(val == 1 || val == 4 || val == 10 || val == 13) liczba_pokoi.show();
  if(val == 2 || val == 3 || val == 11 || val == 12) liczba_pokoi.hide();  

});
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pBxfX/

Answer (score 2):

`else if`, not `if else`.

You should check the syntax error first.

Answer (score 1):

You are using If Else with an incorrect syntax. It has to be like

```
$('select#kategorie').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value=="1" || value=="10")
    {
       $("#liczba-pokoi").css("display","block");
    }
    else if(value=="2" || value=="11")
    {
       $("#liczba-pokoi").css("display","none");
    }
    else if((value=="3" || value=="12")
    {
       $("#liczba-pokoi").css("display","none");
    }
    else if(value=="4" || value=="13")
    {
       $("#liczba-pokoi").css("display","block");
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if else condition should be `else if` instead of `if else`

```
$('select#kategorie').change(function() {

    var value = $('select#kategorie:selected').val();

if (value=="1" || value=="10")
{
$("#liczba-pokoi").css("display","block");
}
else if (value=="2" || value=="11")
{
$("#liczba-pokoi").css("display","none");
}
else if ((value=="3" || value=="12")
{
$("#liczba-pokoi").css("display","none");
}
else if (value=="4" || value=="13")
{
$("#liczba-pokoi").css("display","block");
}
});
```

follow the link to know more. [IF ELSE Statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)